# Multiple client connections in elastic search java rest client bean creation

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, client

Code below is creating a bean to connect to elastic search cluster. The client used is Java High Level Rest Client. Here 2 connections have been made having port 9200 and 9201.

Let's say if I am running this in my local machine wherein I up the elastic search cluster and the default port is 9200, but what is the use case that we can achieve if we use multiple connections.

```
@Override
@Bean
public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {

    
    RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(
            RestClient.builder(
                    new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"),
                    new HttpHost("localhost", 9201, "http")));
    return client;

}
```

This is mentioned in the documentation: **The high-level client will internally create the low-level client used to perform requests based on the provided builder. That low-level client maintains a pool of connections.**

So are these threads in pool communicate with only one cluster or there are two clusters one with host 9200 and other with 9201

Comment: if you have multinode cluster with more then 1 master or coordinate node then you can give that multipul IP and port. so it will work for High Availibility.

Comment: if that is the case, then how can we pass these values in app.properties files and If I am not wrong the coordination will be managed by elastic search

Comment: Yes, if you not configured dedicated coordinate node then elastic take care of it. you can pass as key-value map in spring boot properties file.

Comment: @SagarPatel If we configuring this ourselves, then is there some kind of leader election happening in cases wherein master goes down and someone from coordinate node has to become new master

Comment: yes, if you have multipul master node in your cluster then Elastic will automatically elect the another as master when active amster node goes down. In Elasticsearch, by default all node are enable as cordinator node.